Is there a way to shorten this code to two lines maybe three?
I am still figuring out how to manipulate strings in python.  Currently I need to use 4 lines to go from
('Al Jahar',)

to
'Al Jahar'

This is the code I'm using.  Works great, but would love to make it more elegant and pythonic.
    selected_monster = f"{selected_monster}"
    selected_monster = selected_monster[:-2] + selected_monster[-1]
    selected_monster = selected_monster[:-1]
    selected_monster = selected_monster[1:]
    print(selected_monster)

I can't just strip/ replace the characters "()," with "" because some monster names have those characters in their titles, eg: 'Beholder (blah blah)' or 'Dragon, Green'.
The names ALL come from a db and have this markup around their 'Monster Name' name tag. So if I try the replacement method it messes up the titles and I can't use them as string variables in my code.

Quite possibly you can do it with zero lines if you avoid having that in the first place. Can't tell without seeing your code that created it.

The results coming from a database are not strings.  You get a list of rows, and each row is a tuple of values, even if there is only one.  for row in cursor.fetch_all(): / print(row[0]) will print the first (or only) column in each row.

Thank you for taking the time Tim Roberts, I was not aware that each row was a tuple when I did a cursor.fetch_all :) That was very helpful.

Are you going to show us the code that assigned the variable, so that we can show you the best way to do it (with zero extra lines)?

@nocomment I'm trying to get my code written in here formatted correctly and I'm having trouble figuring that out in this comment area.  It was a basic sql call that returned all the monster names and put them in a CTkListbox with a callback function on mouse click (which I did write in as the answer everyone here helped me figure out.

You can use single backticks to format like in Tim's comment, but I'd put it in the question anyway.

Probably because you asked about something so basic, accessing a tuple element. - ' I didn't include the code that assigned that variable because like I said in my question the names (eg. Al Jahar) come from a db call" - What does it matter that they came from a db call?

Didnt realize a db call returns a tuple. Gap in my knowledge- my bad.

('Al Jahar',) is a tuple. You can determine this by doing
>>> selected_monster = ('Al Jahar',)
>>> type(selected_monster)

To access an element of a tuple, you can just index it:
>>> selected_monster[0]

OR
>>> ('Al Jahar',)[0]

You can also use tuple unpacking. The version below is if you're sure it contains only one element:
>>> selected_monster, = selected_monster

If you're not sure, stash the remainder elsewhere:
>>> selected_monster, *_ = selected_monster

You may also want to reconsider how you generate selected_monster in the first place, if you need it to be a string.

Thank you very much for the advice!  I'm still learning all the ins and outs of python and wasn't familiar with the short hand of using type(selected_monster) like that.  That is extremely helpful knowledge.

Glad this was useful to you. You can upvote and select the answer by clicking on the arrow and check mark on the left of it.

After the input from the users here it seems like I can in fact do what I want with zero lines of extra code.
Instead of messing with the tuple as if it were a string, I can bypass that and simply call the element of the tuple my previous sql query returned.
My usage becomes (paired down), this:
    sql = f"SELECT Frequency FROM Monsters WHERE Name = '{selected_monster[0]}'"


Hmm, yeah, that's another way to use zero extra lines. Not the one I meant, where you'd have the string in the variable so you wouldn't need the [0] (And likely it would only take one extra character instead of three:-)
